# weka not represent all the attributes

Tags: weka

I created an arff file, then I opened the file in Weka. Weka read the file as one attribute while I have ten attributes. Can anyone help me to solve this issues? 
The code and Weka result are shown below

```
@Relation  Dentition_Records
@attribute  N            NUMERIC 
@attribute  Animal       String
@attribute  I            NUMERIC
@attribute  i            NUMERIC
@attribute  C            NUMERIC
@attribute  c            NUMERIC
@attribute  P            NUMERIC
@attribute  p            NUMERIC
@attribute  M            NUMERIC
@attribute  m            NUMERIC

@Data
1;Opossum;5;4;1;1;3;3;4;4
2;Hairy tail mole;3;3;1;1;4;4;3;3
3;Common mole;3;2;1;0;3;3;3;3
4;Star nose mole;3;3;1;1;4;4;3;3
5;Brawn bat;2;3;1;1;3;3;3;3
6;Sliver hair bat;2;3;1;1;2;3;3;3
7;Pigmy bat;2;3;1;1;2;2;3;3
8;House bat;2;3;1;1;1;2;3;3
9;Red bat;1;3;1;1;2;2;3;3
10;Hoary bat;1;3;1;1;2;2;3;3
11;Lump nose bat;2;3;1;1;2;3;3;8
12;Armadillo;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3
13;Pika;2;1;0;0;2;2;3;3
14;Snowshoe rabbit;2;1;0;0;3;2;3;3
15;Beaver;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
16;Marmot;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
17;Groundhog;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
18;Prairie Dog;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
19;Ground Squirrel;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
20;Chipmunk;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
21;Gray swuirrel;1;1;0;0;2;1;3;3
22;Fox squirrel;1;1;0;0;1;1;3;3
23;Pocket gopher;1;1;0;0;1;1;3;3
24;Kangaroo rat;1;1;0;0;1;1;3;3
25;Pack rat;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;3
26;Field mouse;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;3
27;Muskrat;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;3
28;Black rat;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;3
29;House mouse;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;3
30;Porcupine;1;1;0;0;1;1;3;3
31;Guinea pig;1;1;0;0;1;1;3;3
32;Coyote;1;1;1;1;4;4;3;3
33;Wolf;3;3;1;1;4;4;2;3
34;Fox ;3;3;1;1;4;4;2;3
35;Bear;3;3;1;1;4;4;2;3
36;Civet cat;3;3;1;1;4;4;2;2
37;Raccon;3;3;1;1;4;4;3;2
38;Marten;3;3;1;1;4;4;1;2
39;Ficher;3;3;1;1;4;4;1;2
40;Weasel;3;3;1;1;3;3;1;2
41;Mink;3;3;1;1;3;3;1;2
42;Ferrer;3;3;1;1;3;3;1;2
43;Wolverine;3;3;1;1;4;4;1;2
44;Badger;3;3;1;1;3;3;1;2
45;Skunk;3;3;1;1;3;3;1;2
46;River otter;3;3;1;1;4;3;1;2
47;Sea otter;3;2;1;1;3;3;1;2
48;Jaguar;3;3;1;1;3;2;1;1
49;Ocelot;3;3;1;1;3;2;1;1
50;Cougar;3;3;1;1;3;2;1;1
51;Lynx;3;3;1;1;3;2;1;1
52;Fur seal;3;2;1;1;4;4;1;1
53;Sea Lion;3;2;1;1;4;4;1;1
54;Walrus;1;0;1;1;3;3;0;0
55;Grey seal;3;2;1;1;3;3;2;2
56;Elephant seal;2;1;1;1;4;4;1;1
57;Peccary;2;3;1;1;3;3;3;3
58;ELK;0;4;1;0;3;3;3;3
59;Deer;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
60;Moose;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
61;Reindeer;0;4;1;0;3;3;3;3
62;Antelope;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
63;Bison;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
64;Mountain goat ;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
65;Musk ox;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
66;Mountain sheep;0;4;0;0;3;3;3;3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace all semicolons `;` with commas `,` surround all strings with `'` and your file will work just fine.

Example:

```
@Relation  Dentition_Records

@attribute  N            NUMERIC 
@attribute  Animal       String
@attribute  I            NUMERIC
@attribute  i            NUMERIC
@attribute  C            NUMERIC
@attribute  c            NUMERIC
@attribute  P            NUMERIC
@attribute  p            NUMERIC
@attribute  M            NUMERIC
@attribute  m            NUMERIC

@Data
1,Opossum,5,4,1,1,3,3,4,4
4,'Star nose mole',3,3,1,1,4,4,3,3
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you!